# error: variable or field 'print_array' declared void

Tags: c++

My compiler is throwing the error `error: variable or field 'print_array' declared void` on the line of my function declaration in the following piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct arrWrapper
{
    T* firstPtr;
    size_t length;
};

template <typename T>
void print_array(arrWrapper W)
{
    for (T* i(W.firstPtr), j(W.firstPtr + W.length); i != j; i++)
        std::cout << *i << ", ";
}

int main()
{
    int myArray[] = {1, 2, 69, 144};
    arrWrapper myWrapper = {myArray, sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(int)};
    print_array(myWrapper)

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone shed some insight on why I'm getting that error?

**I have another question:** Does anyone know how I can check whether a variable is able to be printed to the console using `std::cout`?

In other words, I'd like to change my function to something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void print_array(arrWrapper W)
{
    /* check whether I can cout an element of type T, and if so, 
       terminate the function here
    */
    for (T* i(W.firstPtr), j(W.firstPtr + W.length); i != j; i++)
        std::cout << *i << ", ";
}
```

Comment: `arrWrapper` is a class template. You need to instantiate it with a template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
template <typename T>
void print_array(arrWrapper<T> W)
//                         ^^^ provide a template parameter
```

the same for

```
arrWrapper<int> myWrapper = //...
```

later in your code.

---

For the second question: You could disable the function with C++11's type-traits (or use the Boost-version for pre-C++11):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof(std::cout<<std::declval<T>())!=0>::type
print_array(arrWrapper<T> W)
{
    for (T* i(W.firstPtr), j(W.firstPtr + W.length); i != j; i++)
        std::cout << *i << ", ";
}
```

That would result in a compile-time error if `T` can not be printed.

Comment: Also, his usage of `arrWrapper` in `main()` needs a template parameter, and he could use a semicolon after `print_array(myWrapper)`...